# Does pairwise phase incoherence satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: statistics, inequality, complex-numbers, signal-processing, time-series

Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane,
$$ S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}. $$

> For values $z_1^{(1)},z_1^{(2)},z_2^{(1)},z_2^{(2)},\ldots,z_k^{(1)},z_k^{(2)} \in S$, letting
> \begin{align*}
>  A &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}z_j^{(2)}\right| \\
>  B_1 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}\right| \\
>  B_2 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(2)}\right|,
>  \end{align*}
> do we necessarily have that
> \begin{equation} \hspace{30mm} A \geq B_1 + B_2 - k \, ? \hspace{30mm} (1) \end{equation}
> If not, do we necessarily at least have that
> \begin{equation} \hspace{30mm} A^2 \geq B_1^2 + B_2^2 - k^2 \, ? \hspace{26mm} (2) \end{equation}

Note that (1) does indeed imply (2): the triangle inequality gives that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are each at most $k$, and hence
$$ [\text{RHS of (1)}]^2 - \text{RHS of (2)} \ = \ 2(k-B_1)(k-B_2) \ \geq \ 0. $$

---

**Context:** For multivariate data where each coordinate is an angle, it is common to measure the *coherence* (resp. *squared coherence*) between two of the coordinates across the data set, by taking the magnitude (resp. squared magnitude) of the mean of the complex exponential of the difference between the two coordinates. The question is then essentially whether one minus this value defines a metric on the set of coordinates (with Eq. (1) being for coherence and Eq. (2) being for squared coherence). This is a highly relevant question both for phase-coherence of stationary stochastic processes as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing), and for various notions of time-localised phase-coherence such as in Appendix B.1 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520320300750.

Comment: It seems $(1)$ doesn't hold. Consider $(z_1^{(1)}, z_2^{(1)}, z_1^{(2)}, z_2^{(2)})=(1,i,-1,-i)$, then $A=0$ and $B_1=B_2=\sqrt2$, so $A<B_1+B_2-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are counterexamples for $k=2$: let $$z_1^{(1)}=z_1^{(2)}=(1+i)/\sqrt2\ \ \text{and}\ \ z_2^{(1)}=z_2^{(2)}=1,$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \ A=\left|\frac{(1+i)^2}2+1\right|=\sqrt2\ \ \text{and}\ \ B_1=B_2=\left|\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right|=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}.$$
Then $A^2=2<2\sqrt2=B_1^2+B_2^2-k^2$, which means $(2)$ is false and thus $(1)$ is false.

Comment: Thank you for this; I wonder whether, perhaps, you might be able to help with what I realise is the natural follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4783968/222867

Comment: You are welcome, let me check out the new post. (A side note: I remember when trying to write this post, I strongly feel $(2)$ does hold for $k\geq3$, in fact, we can prove $(2)$ holds for $k=3$, but for higher $k$ I have no idea)

Comment: Wow, it’s interesting that (2) should hold for $k=3$. Surely once you’ve got a counterexample for $k=2$, this immediately generates a counterexample for all even $k$ just by repetition, and hence (by continuity) for all sufficiently large odd $k$ as well?

Comment: The follow-up question now has a 200-point bounty [expiring in a week] :)

Comment: @JulianNewman Thanks for letting me know :) It's just that I don't have any good lead on this question for quite a while, so I haven't posted anything, sorry about this. I will update this post or answer the follow-up question as soon as I have some promising results.